# No error on Oracle Unique Constraint on non-key field?

Tags: java, oracle, class, debugging, jakarta-ee

How do I need to handle a unique_constraint on non-key attribute ? I am using Oracle database.

I have a set unique constraint on username field. (emp_id is primary key but I have to check on emp_username). When I intentionally insert a duplicate username, my program is stuck, instead of displaying any error in console while debugging.

```
   String sql = "insert into employee(emp_username, emp_password) values (\'"+username+"\', \'"+password+"\')";
   statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

But on command line duplicate insertion shows an error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (USMAN.UNIQUE_USERNAME) violated
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I fully understand what you are asking for. Is the problem that you don't get an exception back when inserting a duplicate record? Please post the full code piece of your program.

Comment: If your program hangs, it is most likely waiting on a locked row... Did you first try to insert on command line and then ran your program, without commit/rollback in the other session?

Answer (score 0):

it seems here that the problem is not in your code(Your code is fine), it's in the data that you are trying to insert, the username column is unique, so you can't insert value multiple times in that column .